# Cannot update membership status (No drop down)

Tags: civimember

After upgrading to Civicrm 5.21 (it's now on 5.5.3) there is no longer a drop down for changing membership when Status override is enabled.

This was working on 4.7 but sadly after the upgrade it seems to be just static.

[Here is the example](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/cancelling-and-expiring-memberships/) from the documentation

[image: Example]

Any help much appreciated!

Update: So I fixed a JS error (maybe something with git, was in there as lower case).  **No fix for the drop down issue yet though..**

Comment: Can you check if you have any javascript error on browser console?

Comment: The current version of CiviCRM is 5.5.3 and any version lower than 5.3.1 is insecure.

Comment: @PradeepNayak No JS errors and  I'm aware it needs to be on 5.3.1 or newer ASAP.  Could there be a missing permission?

Comment: Yes it does. Can you please upgrade it to latest version and check as its working at our end

Comment: @PradeepNayak I've moved up to 5.3.1 already but no help there, I'll try latest on staging and see.

Comment: @PradeepNayak Issue persists on 5.5.3 too, has to be some form of config or something? I'm not well versed with what's supposed to achieve the dropdown, anything I can check?

Comment: Try changing the status override dropdown so that the status is selectable

Comment: @PradeepNayak I get 3 options for status override, no, permanently and until date. None of these options change member status to a drop down. All I get is what is pictured in OP.  This was available when Civi was on 4.7 so not sure what's changed here. Previously there was a checkbox for overide and a drop down as per https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/cancelling-and-expiring-memberships/ .

Comment: I am able to change membership status on civicrm version 5.5.3

Comment: @HassanFarooq Is there something that I may need to enable? permission? It's only been caused by updating so wondering if something was implemented where I need to toggle something on but can't find anything.. :D

Comment: is this reproducible on dmaster.demo.civi.org. if not, and if this was a bug, then it has been fixed, in which case upgrading is one solution, the other is finding the patch and backporting. since 5.3.x was a security release it seems like an upgrade would be the route to take

Comment: @petednz-fuzion I've moved up to latest and this hasn't resolved the issue unfortunately.

Comment: ok but that isn't quite the same as reproducing on dmaster since the latter will include fixes that have not yet been released

Comment: Not sure what to try next to be honest :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upgrading check all customised files include all the correct changes for your current version.

I was missing a section of code in the membership template.

Comment: Oh - so tripped up by your own customisations? You should 'Accept' this answer and help close this off.